# падежи местоимений (что и чего)

Tags: грамотная-речь, местоимения

Смысл  употребления  формы "чего происходит?" вместо "что происходит?"

Answer (score 1):

Смысл в том, что форма ***чего*** — это разговорно-просторечный вариант местоимения ***что***. Как известно, формы родительного и винительного падежа в ряде случаев являются взаимозаменяемыми, а употребление универсального слова  ***чего*** упрощает речь. Иногда это разговорный вариант, а иногда грубо-просторечный.

Из орфографического словаря: [http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=чего&all=x](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE&all=x)

**чего (форма местоим. что; сниж. к что)**

**Примеры:**

Подошел я ближе, спрашиваю: ― **Чего** тут происходит? [М. М. Зощенко. Жертва революции (1923)]

― Ну, показывай свое хозяйство. **Чего** у тебя тут? ― командует Игорь бедному Фену. [Ольга Андреева. Стланная стлана // «Русский репортер», 2014]

Я спрашиваю, **чего** случилось? [Владимир Войнович. Москва 2042 (1986)]